# Conditionally Rendered Web Components and Stylesheet Links

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

So I'm working on a micro-frontend architecture POC right now, using Web Components to wrap around code from any other framework out there. The goal is to have pieces of the UI be individually deployable to different hosts and simply pulled into the "parent" app (ie, the one that the user navigates to).

I've got most of my architecture working, but right now I'm trying to integrate the Shadow DOM into my work. My current design is to load both the JS and CSS through global static link/script tags, as shown below. Without the Shadow DOM, this works perfectly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://micro-fe.com/file.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <web-component></web-component>
    <script src="http://micro-fe.com/file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Once I mount the content inside my Web Component using the Shadow DOM, however, this breaks down. The stylesheet I am loading in the page header is no longer able to touch the content within the Web Component. That is my ultimate goal for using the Shadow DOM, but that means I need a different way of loading my CSS. The goal is to load it from an external stylesheet like it is now, and not have it inlined in a  tag. Something like this:

```
// Code is inside Web Component. "this" is HTMLElement
const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
const link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'http://micro-fe.com/file.css';
shadowRoot.appendChild(link);
```

I haven't tested that yet, but I've read that  tags are supposed to work from within the Shadow DOM. This, in theory, will get me my scoped styles in the Web Component.

My final challenge, and the reason I am posting this question, has to do with conditional rendering. My  won't always be on the page. Other logic around it will determine when I want that content rendered. So my concern is that I don't want the CSS file to have to be re-loaded each time the component gets rendered.

I'm considering browser caching as a possible solution, but in general I'm wondering if there are any tips that can be provided. I know this is a bit complicated and non-standard, but my ultimate goal is to solve all of these problems and publish a library that does it all out of the box to make it easier for others.

Comment: Drawback of using ``<link>`` inside ShadowDOM as Supersharp correctly suggest is you are introducing a dependency. You could in the final Production (or from the start) phase include all CSS as text in a ``<style>`` tag inside your component so you end up with **one single file** (my personal preference for Components).. but this of course then makes your download (slightly) bigger even if your component is never used on a page and CSS-in-JS is never good to read.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't tested that yet, but I've read that tags are supposed to work from within the Shadow DOM. This, in theory, will get me my scoped styles in the Web Component.

Yes, you can use `<link>` inside Shadow DOMs.

> So my concern is that I don't want the CSS file to have to be re-loaded each time the component gets rendered. I'm considering browser caching as a possible solution, but in general I'm wondering if there are any tips that can be provided.

Yes, thanks to browser caching the CSS file will only be downloaded the first time it is needed.